# Is the natives tag useful

Tags: discussion, tags

I was searching the tags and happened to discover the [natives](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natives) tag. The tag has all of [one question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17485/do-pawpaws-do-well-in-common-landscape-settings-in-hardiness-zones-6b) to it's name. My first instinct was that the tag would have something to do with either A) suggestions for trying to landscape/garden primarily with native plants or B) questions about whether or not a plant you found/have is native to your area. However, the tag does not even have a wiki page to explain it's proper use.

So, what's the story? Should the tag be used for purpose A or B? Or is the tag not particularly useful at all and it should just be thrown away?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a singleton that isn't particularly useful (this one isn't) you have two options:

1. remove it with an edit
2. let it age away naturally

If the question has other issues, you can edit it an remove the tag and do other things. If it's just a tag edit, if the question is otherwise decent then this is a good thing to edit out.

However, if the question is poor and really doesn't merit anymore front page space, just leave it alone (unless you can fix it!). Tags that are only ever used on one question (and don't have a tag wiki) will be automatically deleted after a period of time.

Lastly, if you notice a tag that *is* useful but is only used once, find another question it belongs on, or provide a tag wiki for it so that it does not age away.

Comment: I removed the tag on that question. My intention was to abide by your criteria. It seems well-written with no glaring need for further edits; has a good number of votes on both the question and the answers; and is timely in terms of interest, making a move to the front reasonable in my mind. I hope that was ok!